# Background thread not closing on exiting application

Tags: c#, multithreading

I've got a strange error in my app: I have a single background thread and multiple normal threads. When I close the application, all the normal threads exit eventually, while the background one continues to work.

I've checked in the parallel stacks, and the background  thread remains the only one working.

How can I check if the the application is exiting so I can exit the background thread from inside?

Comment: Double check this. A bg thread should (always) terminate on exit. Is it really blocking the Quit or is the main thread waiting for something?

Comment: This is doing it backwards.  The simple and reliable way is to let the app tell the thread to exit.  Easily done with a AutoResetEvent.  Thread.IsBackground is the best way to ask for a rude abort.

Comment: if 'Thread.IsBackground=true;', there should be no problem like this.  I have not seen one yet.

Comment: may be, there shouldn't be, but here I am, waiting for the background thread to exit several minutes after all the other threads are dead. And yes, it's marked as background, I've double-checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application has a reference to the background thread, call `thread.Abort()` method on termination of application.

Depending on used framework there are other options. For example in WPF the background thread may handle `Application.Exit` event:

```
new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
{
    var thread = Thread.CurrentThread;

    Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
    {
        Exit += (obj, args) => thread.Abort();
    });

    while (true) ; // background thread is always busy
})).Start();
```